# Can I distribute personal and work iOS apps with one Apple Developer account without conflicts?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, apple-developer-account

As an iOS developer working for a company, I have been added to their Apple program as a developer. However, I would like to build and distribute my own personal app to the App Store without any conflicts between my personal and work apps.

Can I do this with just one Apple Developer account by enrolling as an individual and switching between individual and organization modes, or do I need to create a separate account? If it is possible with just one account, how can I ensure that my personal and work apps remain separate?

Comment: When connecting to Apple developer you can select which enrolment you are connected on : Company name or your user name. So if you select your user name you work with your own enrolment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a single account. In Xcode go to Settings (Cmd + ,), you can see your Apple ID and the teams you are a part of.

When creating your own apps, be sure to select the proper Apple ID and team.